# what is the difference between extern char **environ and extern char *environ[]

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char *environ[];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int index = 0;
    char **env = environ;
    printf("Environment variables:\n");
    index = 0;
    while (env[index])
    {
        printf("envp[%d]: %s\n", index, env[index]);
        ++index;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Environment variables:  
envp[0]: GH#þ
```

I want to print all the environments, but it can't work.
I changed `extern char *environ[]` to `extern char **environ` and it can print all the environments.
After changing the code output:

```
Environment variables:
envp[0]: XDG_SESSION_ID=8
envp[1]: TERM=xterm
envp[2]: SHELL=/bin/bash
envp[3]: SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.224 1085 22
envp[4]: SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
...
```

Comment: One is a pointer and one is an array. Contrary to popular belief, arrays are not the same as pointers.

Comment: @interjay -- a source of confusion for learners is that array types are adjusted to pointer types in function declarators, i.e. `char *argv[]` is adjusted to `char **argv` in function declarators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find this stuff impossible to follow without considering what is actually in memory, and how it is organized.

Somewhere in memory are a bunch of blocks of data that contain environment strings -- "foo=bar", "hello=world", and so on. Let's suppose for the sake of argument that "foo=bar" is at address 100, and "hello=world" is at address 200.

Somewhere else in memory is another block of data that lists the addresses of those data blocks (often followed by a zero, so we know where the list actually ends, if we don't know the size in advance}. So this block contains the data

{100,200,0}

If I defined this data as `char *env[]` that would mean that there is a place in memory called `env`, and at that place is the actual data block {100,200,0}. That is, the data at `env` itself would be the number 100, which is the address of one of the environment strings. The next location after `env` would contain 200, and the next after that 0 (OK, I'm simplifying a bit).

If I defined the data block {100,200,0} as a `char **`, that would mean there is a place in memory called `env` that contains the address of the data block {100,200,0}. The data stored at `env` would *not* be "100" (the address of a string). It would be an address that indicates the start of the data block {100,200,0}.

In a C program, the environment is, in fact, a `char **`, that is, the thing called `environ` is not the start of a list of addresses of strings, it is the address of a list of addresses of strings. To see that, you can define it wrongly, and then correct it, as in this modified version of the original code:

```
extern char *environ[];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int index = 0;
    char **env = (char **)environ[0];
    printf("Environment variables:\n");
    index = 0;
    while (env[index])
    {
        printf("envp[%d]: %s\n", index, env[index]);
        ++index;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using `char *environ[]` tells the compiler that (wrongly) the location called `environ` begins a list of pointers to strings, arranged one after another in memory from that point onwards. In fact, only the data at the exact location `environ` is relevant. We can think of that data as `environ[0]`, and just cast it to the real data type, which is a `char **`.

The differences between a `char **` and a `char *[]` are eroded, and thus made confusing, by the fact that C won't allow an array to be passed to a function. All arguments to functions are a single number -- either an primitive like an integer or float, or the address of something. If you try to pass an array (that is, a block of data), the address of the start of the block is passed instead. This means that in most code, you can actually use `char **` and `char *[]` as if they were the same thing. You get problems -- as in this question -- when the data is arranged in memory in a certain way, and the compiler cannot work out what that way is unless the programmer tells it by using the proper type declaration.

Answer (score 4):

As a global declaration `extern char *environ[];` declares an array of pointers to `char`, which is a very different beast from `extern char **environ;` declaring a pointer to a pointer to `char`.

What may be confusing is that both syntaxes can be used interchangeably for a function argument to declare a pointer to a pointer to `char` as in:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

And

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

Some programmers prefer the first syntax to emphasize the fact that `argv` points to an array of strings, not just a single one. Note also that a count of elements could also be specified but would be completely ignored by the compiler:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[2]) { // 2 is ignored
```

Comment: I find this behavior in function declarators to be a continuing source of confusion for learners....

Comment: Hmm. Global `char *environ[];` is a _tentative definition_ and is then a potential incomplete declaration.  To well answer the question, that form is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Extern actually gives reference of the global variable that is visible to all the program files.

Pointer to pointer it retains the assignment or memory allocation outside the function call. The first pointer is used to store the address of the second pointer due to that its called as double pointers.

1. `extern char **environ` : It means the list of environments.(Other words double pointer).
2. `extern char *environ[]`: It means array of pointers.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what the difference is between a "double pointer" and a "pointer to an []array" and why that makes only one of them correct in this context?  (I _think_ I know, but OP doesn't, and I'm not sure enough of it myself to try to explain it myself.)

Comment: The second is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. And there is just one environment, not a "list of environments".

Comment: @interjay, I mean to say pointer arrays. I will correct that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`char **environ` is a pointer to an address, which is a pointer to `char`.
`char *environ[]` is an array of pointers to `char`.

Here is an example :
`char array[] = "foo"` => `array[1]` will get the adress of `array` and move 1 char after
`char *pointer = "bar"` => `pointer[1]` will get the address *pointed by* `pointer`, and move 1 char after

So pointer and array are closely related, but different.

Check http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html. There is a very complete explanation on pointer, much more than this little answer.